# Wrong nginx or dns configuration?

Tags: nginx, dns

I deployed a website on digitalocean with nginx as a proxypass. The Site works but sometimes I have to refresh to reach the site. I am afraid that my nginx or my dns configuration is wrong, since I'm doing this the first time.

Here is my nginx config: (the server should run only on https)

```
   server {
      listen 80;
      server_name <site_name>.com;
      return 301 https://www.<site_name>.com$request_uri;
   }

   server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.<site_name>.com;
      return 301 https://www.<site_name>.com$request_uri;
   }

   server {
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name <site_name>.com;

      # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/private.key;
      return 301 $scheme://www.<site_name>.com$request_uri;
   }

   server {
      listen 443;
      server_name www.<site_name>f.com;

      fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
      fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

      ssl on;
      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/private.key;

      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!AESGCM;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
      ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
      ssl_session_timeout 10m;

      location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
      }
   }
```

Here are my dns settings:

A Record host:@ value: TTL: automatic

A Record host:www value:  TTL: 1 min

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thx!

Comment: The DNS TTL is irrelevant. There may well be a DNS problem, but you have chosen to prevent anyone from helping you there. _Why_ are you people so deadly afraid of revealing the names of web sites you are actively trying to _publish_?

Comment: Hi there, the site is www.c-def.com. I think it depends, if you have a security issue or bad configuration you don't want to publish your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the site fails to load what is the error message, if any? I doubt this is a DNS issue, since it works *sometimes.*

Comment: There is no error message, simply the site doesn't respond. After refreshing everything works fine.

Comment: Sounds like a timeout between your proxy server and application. I'd recommend looking at the log files of both and using `netstat` to examine when they communicate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't find any indicators in the log files. There was one error in the handshake between client and server (but long time ago). Since the error is difficult to reproduce I think the right approach is to observe and if it accords to check the logs.